# Oracle 11g not allowing to connect to. Error ORA-01122: database file 1 failed verification check

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, windows, express-edition

I am running Oracle 11g on Windows 7 Enterprise SP2 16 GB RAM, 1 TB HD. I can connect to Oracle using SQL Plus (see below),

C:>sqlplus sys/xxxxxxxxx@XE as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Jul 9 18:52:26 2014
Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

... but when JDeveloper or another commercial application try to connect to I get the following error:

ORA-01033: Oracle initialization or shutdown in progress ...

Any clue or help would be really appreciated.

Thanks,

XMLDeveloper

Comment: database is not open. Alter database open. But you mentioned an alert in your title? Can you elaborate or post the alert.log part?

Answer (score 1):

Did you do anything like renaming datafiles or moving them around in the filesytem?
The ORA-01122 indicates that the information in the controlfile does not match your environment.

So if you do a shutdown/restart of the database and still get the error *and* moved files around you should move/rename the files to their original places/names and try again.

If all this does not work, have a look at MOS 1041424.6 for details.